# LAMP xdebug loaded, but not creating any file anywhere

Tags: apache2, xdebug-profiler

I have following setup in php.ini (Apache 2.4 / PHP 5.5 / Fedora 19):

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.show_local_vars=On
xdebug.dump_undefined=On
xdebug.collect_return=On
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
```

By using PHP info, I can see Xdebug loaded and all setup directives properly loaded.
However, I can't see any cachecgrind output anywhere.

I've tried so much variations with some directives, using /tmp or /var/tmp + also different file names. Currently I left it as it's by default.

SeLinux is disabled.
/tmp has proper permissions.
I have tried with _trigger directive and also with enabled by default.
Without any cachegrind file anywhere, confirmed by using updatedb & locate cachegrind.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm also having the same problem.

Comment: nope :( I logged new bug http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=993 , but there isn't any response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this worked for me:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = xdebug.out.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/www/projects/myproject/xdebug
```

I've put the profiler_output_dir in the same directory as my virtual site which I'm trying to profile.

Comment: well, this is one thing, that I simply forgot to try - to put output within Apache web root, and it DOES work! I forgot, that Apache (resp. virtual host) CAN be locked in chroot, many thanks.
Finally, it's not a solution, but I can accept it as workaround and add comment to my Xdebug ticket..

Comment: Putting the `profile_output_dir` in the DOCUMENT ROOT worked for me as well. Thank you!